# Chinese Letters Support: Events Are Not Fired After Selecting a Chinese Letter in IME

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, ime

I am writing a text editor for a GWT based web application.
I have a problem with languages such as Chinese, where the standart keyboard is not enough, and the user needs to use IME to enter his input.

There are 3 options to enter a Chinese letter via the IME:
1. type a letter, and then a number, to select the required letter from the list.
2. Type a letter, and then space, to select the first letter in the list
3. Type a letter, and click with your mouse on the required letter.

The first option works fine, and fires KeyPressEvent.
For the second and third options- I never get any events indicating that a letter was selected.

Do I have to make changes to my code to support IME?

Any help will be appreciated.